# Incorrect string value: '\x…” error running on MySQL

Tags: mysql

My Web application uses mvc3 and mysql. It is multilangual. I can not add (create) persian posts and it generates Incorrect string value: '\x…” on column _title at row 1.

I have added charset=utf8 on my connectionstring. I have charset utf8 and collation utf8_general_ci on all columns and the table.
When I run Show Variables like '%olla%' on my database it gives me following:

collation_connection         utf8_general_ci 
collation_database       utf8_general_ci 
collation_server         latin1_swedish_ci

but still it generates same error.
thanks for your advice.

Comment: It is solved by adding Convert(_title using(utf8)) in my insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but you could try to also set the server character set to utf-8 instead of swedish:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-server.html

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I have my application on a Host company and I have no rights to change it. but I don't think if it solvs my problem. because I have already change encoding (charset and colleatíon) on my database and if it was the problem so it should render the text as strange characters. I get error only when I post my text to database.

Comment: I have solve it by adding following in my insert statement
Convert(_title using(utf8))
Insert into table1 values('k1',convert('[chinese string]' using utf8));

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem, and found that this (using charset utf8mb4 instead of utf8) may be the cleanest solution:  [MySQL bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64180)